# $ U_{xx}+U_{yy}=0$ with rectangular boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

When solving
  $ U_{xx}+U_{yy}=0$ with $u(0,y)=u(a,y)=u(x,b)=0,u(x,0)=f(x)$.
$0<=x<=a$ ,  $0<=y<=b$   by the method of separation of variables I have
$-X''(x)-\lambda X(x)=0 $
$Y''(y)-\lambda Y(y)=0$

In $\lambda>0$  case letting $\lambda=\omega^2$  I have come up to
$Y(y)=C e^{\omega y}+D e^{ -\omega y}$.
Is there a way I can write this in the form

$Y(y)=A_n cosh(\omega y)+B_n sinh(\omega y)$  . 
After this using the boundary condition $u(x,b)=0$,   I get $Y(b)=0$.
Then is there a way to write $Y(y)=A_n cosh(\omega (y-b))+B_n sinh(\omega (y-b))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way but only when $\lambda < 0$, then $Y$ can be written in form:

$Y(y)=C_1 e^{i\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+D_1 e^{-i\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$, but on the other hand:

$e^{i\sqrt{-\lambda}}=\cos{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+i\sin{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$ and

$e^{-i\sqrt{-\lambda}}=\cos{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+i\sin{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}=\cos{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}-i\sin{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$, so when we substitute to equation $Y(y)=C_1 e^{i\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+D_1 e^{-i\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$ we have (with other constans $C,D$)

$Y(x)=C\cos{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+D\sin{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$

If you don't want to use complex numbers you can simply check that for $\lambda<0$ solution is like above ($\sin$ and $\cos$ are linear independent so it's general solution of this equation).

If you want to swap $e^{\omega x}$ and $e^{-\omega x}$ to $\sinh{\omega x}$ and $\cosh{\omega x}$ use this:

$\sinh(z)=\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}$

$\cosh(z)=\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2}$

$Y(x)=Ce^{\omega x}+De^{\omega x}=\frac{C-D+C+D}{2}e^{\omega x}+\frac{C+D-(C-D)}{2}e^{-\omega x}$

if we substitute $A=C+D$ and $B=C-D$ we have

$\frac{A+B}{2}e^{\omega x}+\frac{B-A}{2}e^{-\omega x}=A\sinh \omega x+B\cosh \omega x$

Comment: : When $\lambda<0$ for $X(x)$ I get the trivial solution

Comment: I can convert $Y(y)=C e^{\omega y}+D e^{ -\omega y}$ into $Y(y)=A_n cosh(\omega y)+B_n sinh(\omega y)$ if I let C=A+B and D=A-B where A,B are constants.But is it justifiable to let it like that?Also is it necessary to convert it to sinh and cosh or can I just do it using the form $Y(y)=C e^{\omega y}+D e^{ -\omega y}$ .I am trying to convert it to cosh sinh form because that's how it is doe in page **4** of http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~marvin/402/exercise.solutions/SOL19.pdf

Comment: Yes, it's justifiable, because it's only the other way to write down the solution, for example for$C=D=\frac{1}{2}$ we have $Y(x)=\frac{e^{\omega x}+e^{-\omega x}}{2}$ and it's simply $\cosh \omega x$. You can write this in this form but it's not necessary.

Comment: : I still don't understand how it is justifiable.Can you please explain it a little bit more

Comment: I've written it in my answer.

Comment: :Without converting it to sinh cosh I did the problem.Then $Y(y)=De^{\omega y}(e^{-2\omega y}-e^{-2\omega b})$.Thus $u(x,y)=Bsin({n\pi x \over a})De^{\omega y}(e^{-2\omega y}-e^{-2\omega b})$.Thus $(1-e^{-2\omega b})\sum a_n sin({n\pi x \over a}) =f(x)$.                                                                                                                                      $a_n=\int_0^a{f(x)sin({n\pi x \over a}) dx \over (1-e^{-2\omega b}) } $.Can you please tell me if this is correct

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but you forgot $\frac{2}{a}$ (it's in your solutions) :) If you want have $a_n$ without $1-e^{2\omega b}$ you can put $b_n=a_n(1-e^{2 \omega b})$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the given help